# Infopath Run Action Rule before Validation

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, infopath, infopath-rules

Is it possible with Infopath and SharePoint 2010, to run a Action rule before a Validation rule? When adding the rules it places Validation above Action with no option to move down. I am attempting to do this out of the box.

Target Functionality: I have a combo box with data in it, which I compare to data from a list. When changing the combobox it needs to query the data before it runs the validation.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, try following:

1) On Changing combo box, write rule to query data

2) After query data action, add action to copy new value to a hidden text box

3) Write required validation rule on text box changed event.